# Second level vue route throws error when accessed directly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, vuex

I am using vue-router in my vue application. I have the following routes in my application.

```
const routes = [
    {name: "home", path: "/", component: Home},
    {name: "user", path: "/user", component: User},
    {name: "edit-user", path: "/user/edit", component: EditUser}
];

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: routes,
    mode: 'history'
});
```

Here both the routes are working perfectly when accessed using `router-link` as given below.

```
<router-link to="/user">Go to user</router-link>
<router-link to="/user/edit">Edit user</router-link>
```

If I am accessing the routes directly by page refresh the route "/user" works perfectly. But the route "/user/edit" shows a black page with just the following error in the console (without any other error details).

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Can anyone help me out to solve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It was caused due to a very small reason. In my main HTML page, the js file was linked as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
```

The issue was fixed by changing the src value from `"js/app.js"` to `"/js/app.js"` as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 18):

I was facing the same issue I resolved this by adding

`publicPath: '/'`

in my Webpack config file suggested on https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware/issues/205#issuecomment-315847782

Thanks to **[Mark M. Muskardin](https://github.com/hackingbeauty)**

Comment: Thanks.
I was facing the same error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ===="
when using second level (e.g "comments/1") and it was solved by adding '/' to vue.config.js

Here is my vue.config.js:
module.exports = {
    baseUrl: '/',
 devServer: {
  disableHostCheck: true,

 }
}